# Delphi borland Debug exe файл tds Какие структуры внутри

Tags: delphi, отладка

Где можно почитать документацию какие структуры данных хранит debug exe в файле **.tds**?

Нужно для того что получить как имена адреса локальных переменных при ошибке так и имя процедуры.

библиотека *Jc*l частично решает эту проблему и там можно получить имя процедуры.
A вот локальными переменными она не владеет.

Когда компилятор генерит ***exe*** он в каком то же формате заносит адреса локальных переменных
т.к в самом ***exe*** имена переменных есть. И сам отладчик позволяет просматривать текущее значение переменных
как он это делает?

Кстати, [модуль Jcl](https://searchcode.com/file/5297907/Gedemin/jcl/source/windows/JclTD32.pas/)
который парсит сам ***exe*** получает имена локальных переменных
это просто массив строк
а должна быть еще одна структура там где будет
index на эту строку
offset от VA
и наверно OffsetProcedure адрес процедуры кому принадлежит лок переменная
а вот такой структуры я не нашел в модуле JclTD32.pas
и если бы нашел то с какого места начать ее парсить тож пока не ясно.
хотя это уже лучше чем ничего.

я только смог найти вот такой pdf там есть основная структура exe
а структура отладочной инфы там нет
наверно каждый компилятор сам решает как ее записывать
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3_wGJkuWLytbnIxY1J5WUs4MEk/view?resourcekey=0-n5zZ2UW39xVTH8ZSu6C2aQ

что вселяет уверенность на успешный поиск эт то что в отладчике delphi все работает.

возможно как то через winApi можно или Dbghlp но даж не знаю что искать нужно.
Кто бы тыкнул носом в какую ссылку структур

Answer (score 0):

Буду сам с себе писать раз никто не отвечает

мой путь пока такой
[задал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359406/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-c-bordebug-dll-%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-delphi)

там есть ссылка на BorDebug.dll это Api для отлатчика можно получить все что нужно

встает вопрос как это переписать на Delphi?
[по запросу на Git](https://github.com/search?q=BorDebug&type=code)
есть некий модуль от EurekaLog
[ВОТ ОН EBorlandDebug.pas](https://github.com/icew4y/cq_3km2/blob/494a2fb333d1bfb4d7132d7f06cc2fb1e5ee9e30/Working/3K2012/Component/EurekaLog%20v6.0.6%20Enterprise/Delphi7/EBorlandDebug.pas)
там показано как можно работая с BorDebug.dll что то оттуда достать.
Остается  вопрос о необъявленных константах типов и символов пример(**0x120**)
[их нашел здесь](https://github.com/rainers/mago/blob/master/CVSym/CVSym/cvexefmt_old.h)
в delphi они будут определены как

```
SUBSECTION_TYPE_MODULE         = $120;
```

ну и [ссылка](https://getcalc.com/digital-hexa-decimal-calculator.htm) на калькулятор для констант
что в число преобразовать если нужно будет отлаживать сам создаваемый модуль
думаю с этим уже можно работать что бы все в одно собрать

Comment: вопросы здесь принято задавать с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы. дополнить свой вопрос можно, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса. а вот публиковать новые вопросы или дополнения к существующим под видом ответа здесь не принято.

Comment: это не вопрос а ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: или ты робот что читаешь и видишь в тексте вопрос значит это вопрос по твоему. Аллергия на таких модеров