# Код импорта c BorDebug.dll С++ переписать на Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, dllimport

[Eсть BorDebug.dll и есть unit к этой dll на С++](https://github.com/dvb01/BorDebug)
как переписать его под Delphi

сколько я не пытался загрузить процедуры в delphi ничего не выходит
GetProcAddress всегда = NIL
что я не так делаю.

```
procedure BorDebugLoad;
var P:Pointer;
 procedure Loc(S:LPCWSTR);
 begin
   P:= GetProcAddress(BorDebugHandle, S);
   if P<>nil then
   P:=P; // всегда NIL NULL
 end;
begin
  P:=nil;
  BorDebugHandle := SafeLoadLibrary(bordebug_dllname);

  if BorDebugHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    Loc('BorDebugRegisterFile');
    Loc('BorDebugUnregisterFile');
    Loc('BorDebugSubSectionDirOffset');
    Loc('BorDebugSubSectionCount');
    Loc('BorDebugSubSection');
    Loc('BorDebugModule');
    Loc('BorDebugModuleSegment');
    Loc('BorDebugStartSymbols');
    Loc('BorDebugNextSymbol');
    Loc('BorDebugDumpBrowserInfo');
    Loc('BorDebugSymbolCOMPILE');
    Loc('BorDebugSymbolREGISTER');
    Loc('BorDebugSymbolCONST');
    Loc('BorDebugSymbolUDT');

  end;
end;
```

Comment: Следует указывать имена из таблицы экспорта, типа `_BorDebugRegisterFile`

Comment: О!!)) это да работает